# Deforming isometric embeddings in low codimension

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, moser-iteration

Let $F:M\to \mathbb R^N$ be an embedding. This embedding induces a metric $g_F=dF\cdot dF$ on $M$, that turns $F$ into an *isometric* embedding. Probably the hardest part of the proof of the Nash Embedding Theorem is to prove a deformation result of the following type (see e.g. Thm 1.1 [here](http://maths-old.anu.edu.au/research.publications/proceedings/040/CMAproc40-andrews.pdf)):

> **Thm:** If $F:M\to\mathbb R^N$ is a *free* global (analytic) embedding and $h$ is a $C^k$ $(2,0)$-tensor in a neighborhood of zero, then there exists a $C^k$ map $V:M\to\mathbb R^N$ such that $$g_{F+V}=g_F+h, \quad (*)$$ i.e., $F+V$ is a **global** isometric embedding of $(M,g_F+h)$ into $\mathbb R^N$.

The *free* condition means that the vectors $\partial F/\partial x_i$ and $\partial^2 F/\partial x_i\partial x_j$ are linearly independent at every point. The use of the above result to prove the Nash Embedding Theorem is when the ambient dimension $N$ is large, more precisely, $N\geq n(n+3)/2$. In this case, the *free* condition implies that the linearized version of $(*)$ is solvable, and then the problem follows by, e.g., the  Nash-Moser method.
My interest, however, is when $N< n(n+3)/2$. In this case, by *free* we mean that the vectors $\partial F/\partial x_i$ and $\partial^2 F/\partial x_i\partial x_j$ span a subspace with largest possible dimension (although, in the particular case I'm interested, although they do span such a subspace, some of them are identically zero!). In this case, the linearized system is overdetermined, and may not admit solutions...

> My question is if (regardless of the linearized system being solvable or not) there are any known conditions under which the Thm above also holds for free embeddings with $N< n(n+3)/2$. In other words, when can one deform (global) isometric embeddings of $(M,g_0)$ in low codimension to (global) isometric embeddings for all metrics near $g_0$?

The analogous question for *local* isometric embeddings is dealt with in a paper by Bryant, Griffiths and Yang (Duke Math, 1983), but I do not know of any results (or counter-examples) regarding the *global* problem.

Comment: It holds for compact surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$. In this case the embedding is free if and only if the surface is convex, so everything follows from Alexandrov's embedding theorem. 

Comment: @Anton : I don't understand, the definition of free in the question seems to be in this case that the second fundamental form does'nt vanish entirely at a point. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: @BS. There is no free condition. (I think the word "free" was included in the question by mistake --- if it is free, then linearized  system can be solved.) Anyway,  free maps can be deformed, but some nonfree maps can be deformed as well. (Very sorry for late reply.)